# Can I use a custom validation function without a directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm looking at this in my browser:

```
<input class="ng-valid-number ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required" type="number" step="0.01" required="" data-ng-model="obfuscated" min="0.1" max="0.5">
```

That seems strange to me, given the fact that I filled in 42 as a value.

I'd like to use a custom validation function. I don't care for a directive a this point, I just want to do something along the lines of

```
ng-valid-when="expression"
```

Does such a thing exist?

(If you're wondering how I got this to fail, the clue is to use an espression to fill max and min `max="0.5"` works as expected, `max="{{my expression}}"` doesn't.)

#### UPDATE: working directive solution

With a directive:

```
module.directive('withinRange', function () {
return  {
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    var restrictions = scope.$eval(attrs.withinRange);
    scope.$watch(function(){return ngModel.$modelValue}, function(){
      ngModel.$setValidity('min', ngModel.$modelValue >= restrictions.min());
      ngModel.$setValidity('max', ngModel.$modelValue <= restrictions.max());
    });
  }
}
});
```

this works:

```
<input name="input" type="number" step="0.01"
       data-within-range="range" 
       data-ng-model="value"/>
```

---

```
    angular.extend($scope, {value: 0.2,
      range: {
        min: function () {
          return 0.1;
        }, max: function () {
          return 0.9;
        }}});
```

Comment: **What's** strange? **What** failed?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the stellar gap in my question, will fix immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular form validation is expecting a form or input error to have a name. This name is specified in the arguments you pass to `$setValidity`, which you use from the `ngModelController` instance that you require in a directive definition and use in its link function.

Such a `ng-valid-when="expression"` attribute would not pass an error name.

So, you have to build a directive for your error type. Angular is designed this way.

However, you may write your own generic `ngValidExpression` directive which would for example toggle `ng-invalid-expression`/`ng-valid-expression` classes the same way it does with the `ngPattern` attribute.

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing. Wouldn't it work fine if there was a generic directive with a default name though?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exist in Angular. The closest you can get is the [ng-pattern](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput) attribute of the input directive.

See the [manual page for forms](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) for more information on form validation with a directive.

Comment: I've got a working solution with a directive, but if all you need is validation based on business logic accessible through the controller it seems insane. ng-pattern won't do for number range I think.

Comment: Yes, it's annoyingly cumbersome to write custom validation.

Answer (score 1):

I make a solution for multiple validations (one per input) without write multiple validators directive, simply put the validators in the scope and the call those validators as an attribute

### Controller:

```
//...
myRangeValidator = (modelValue, viewValue)=>{...}
$scope.actions.validators.range = myRangeValidator;
$scope.data.number = 0;

myUserNameValidator = (modelValue, viewValue)=>{...}
$scope.actions.validators.userName = myUserNameValidator;
$scope.data.userName = "";
//...
```

### View:

```
<input
  type="number"
  ng-model="data.number"
  dfxpvalidator="actions.validators.range"
>
<input
  type="text"
  ng-model="data.userName"
  dfxpvalidator="actions.validators.userName"
>
```

### Directive:

```
// This directive add a custom validator independent of the directive
// original writed in CS
app.directive( 'dfxpvalidator', [
  '$rootScope',
  '$timeout',
  function($rs, $to){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope:{dfxpvalidator: '='},
      link: function(scope, elements, attrs, model){
        model.$validators.myValidator = scope.dfxpvalidator
      }
    }
  }
])
```